# Change TextField font color in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently using [Material UI](https://mui.com).

And I'm having issues trying to change the font color of the multiline `TextField`.

```
<TextField className = "textfield"
           fullWidth
           multiline
           label   = "Debugger"
           rows    = "10"
           margin  = "normal"/>
```

And the CSS:

```css
.textfield {
    background-color: #000;
    color: green;
}
```

However, somehow I only get the black background and the font is still black. Does anyone know how to properly change the font color of a `TextField` using Material UI?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I referred this page [TextField API](https://mui.com/api/text-field/)

And I override the TextField using Classes

```
const styles = theme => ({
    multilineColor:{
        color:'red'
    }
});
```

Apply the class to TextField using InputProps.

```
<TextField 
  className = "textfield"
  fullWidth
  multiline
  InputProps={{
    className: classes.multilineColor
  }}
  label   = "Debugger"
  rows    = "10"
  margin  = "normal" />
```

**EDIT** In older version you have to specify the key `input`

```
<TextField 
    className = "textfield"
    fullWidth
    multiline
    InputProps={{
        classes: {
            input: classes.multilineColor
        }
    }}
    label   = "Debugger"
    rows    = "10"
    margin  = "normal"
/>
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: I suppose that in the second code area you meant 'input: styles.multilineColor'

Comment: No... it's 'classes' because we are overriding styles using classes which we got from withStyles hoc... Refer this.... https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/demos/text-fields/CustomizedInputs.js

Comment: Refer to this link for answer: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9574

Answer (score 48):

In **Material UI v5**, you can just do this using `sx` prop:

```
<TextField sx={{ input: { color: 'red' } }} />
```

A bit longer approach if you want something more reusable:

```
const options = {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'fontColor',
};
const StyledTextField = styled(
  TextField,
  options,
)(({ fontColor }) => ({
  input: {
    color: fontColor,
  },
}));
```

```
<StyledTextField label="Outlined" fontColor="green" />
<StyledTextField label="Outlined" fontColor="purple" />
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working with the `multiline` property. This exact same code with the `multiline` property stops showing the text color. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: Just adding in to @NearHuscarl 's answer, if you need a gradient instead of a single color, you can achieve that by:-

```
<TextField  variant="standard" sx={{
                    input: {
                      background: 'linear-gradient(97.87deg, #E30647 -28.9%, #FFAA0A 93.4%)',
                      _webkitBackgroundClip: 'text',
                      _webkitTextFillColor: 'transparent',
                      backgroundClip: 'text',
                      textFillColor: 'transparent'
                    }
                  }}
                  />
```

Answer (score 19):

Using `inputProps` is correct, as others have posted. Here's a slightly simpler example:

```
<TextField
  multiline
  inputProps={{ style: { color: "red" } }}
  /* ... */
/>
```

Answer (score 8):

How to set color property and background property of Text Field

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const styles = {
  root: {
    background: "black"
  },
  input: {
    color: "white"
  }
};

function CustomizedInputs(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <TextField
      defaultValue="color"
      className={classes.root}
      InputProps={{
        className: classes.input
      }}
    />
  );
}

CustomizedInputs.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomizedInputs);
```

Comment: Copied from https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9574

Comment: How do you do this in typescript?

Answer (score 6):

```
//textfield customization
const CssTextField = withStyles({
  root: {
    '& .MuiInputBase-root': {
      color: 'white',
    },
  },
})(TextField);
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does so people may understand it?

Comment: @LjmDullaart this essentially creates a wrapper that adds styles. see this  https://mui.com/api/text-field/#css and this https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/ for more details

Comment: "& label":{
          color: 'gainsboro',
        },

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a more generic fix, you can change your theme to contain that color, in my case I needed to change the input background and the disabled as well, so I end up using the ThemeProvider and a custom Theme.

Custom theme

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiInputBase: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          '&.Mui-disabled': {
            backgroundColor: '#e4e4e4',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
const withDefaultTheme =
  <P extends object>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) =>
  (props: any) =>
    (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work !

```
import { TextField, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  input: {
    color: "#FFF",
  },
}));

const MyInput = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TextField
      inputProps={{ className: classes.input }}
      id="outlined-basic"
      label="Write something..."
      variant="outlined"
    />
  );
};

export default MyInput;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working in my case:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {  TextField, } from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    textfield_input: {
        color: `#c5cae9 !important`,
    }
}));

function Videoedit() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (<div>
            <TextField
              value={title}
              required
              label="Title"
              variant="filled"
              inputProps={{className: classes.textfield_input}}
              color="primary"
              focused
            />)
        </div>;
}

export default Videoedit;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mui documentation says you can create styled text field with these properties:

```
const CssTextField = styled(TextField)({
    '& label.Mui-focused': {
      color: 'white',
    },
    '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
      borderBottomColor: 'white',
    },
    '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {
      color: 'white',
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      '& fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'white',
      },
      '&:hover fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'white',
      },
      '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'white',
      },
    },
  });
```

and later you can use

```
<CssTextField label="*" name="*" variant="outlined" size="small" />
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these other approaches worked exactly for what I wanted to do which is have a dark themed one. This works for me with Material 5.x:

```
<TextField
    sx={{
      border: '1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.6)',
      borderRadius: 3,
    }}
    InputLabelProps={{
      style: { color: '#fff', backgroundColor: 'var(--green-80, #184743)' },
    }}
    InputProps={{ style: { color: '#fff' } }}
    id={id}
    label={label}
    variant="outlined"
    size="small"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using styled component with TextField then just write this code inside your styled component:

```
  input: {
    color: '#ffffff',
  },

if you want to change placeholder color:

  label: {
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to take some of the examples - @Asif Mahmood @Karlo Tvrdinic @NearHuscarl - in this thread and apply them to the TextField component directly via to sx prop and utilize the theme object.

Here is an example from my project:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the party, but this is what I used to customise the color for all the text fields in my app. [API here](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/)

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#160033',
      contrastText: '#ffffff',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#BC12B4',
      contrastText: '#F7F5FF',
    },
  },
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      defaultProps: {
        color: "secondary",
        inputProps: {
          style: {
            color: "#160033" // This sets the text field font color
          }
        }
      }
    },
})

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme} >
    // Your css baseline here...
    // Your routing component here...
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <TextField
      required
      id="outlined-required"
      placeholder="Email"
      onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      autoComplete={false}
      size="large"
      sx={{
        mb: "1rem",
        bgcolor: "rgb(51, 51, 51)",
        "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
          color: "white",
          "& > fieldset": {
            borderColor: "rgb(171, 171, 171)",
          },
          "&:hover fieldset": {
            borderColor: "white",
          },
          "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
            borderColor: "white",
          },
        },
      }}
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <EmailOutlined
              sx={{ color: "rgb(171, 171, 171)" }}
              fontSize="large"
            />
          </InputAdornment>
        ),
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score -1):

Use your Component like below

```js
const MyTextField = withStyles({
root: {
"& .MuiInputBase-root.Mui-disabled": {
    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0,0.0)"
},
"& .MuiFormLabel-root.Mui-disabled": {
    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0,0.0)"
},

}
})(TextField);
```

Answer (score -12):

Try below css

```
 .textfield{
     color: #000;
    }
```