# How to change disabled MUI TextField text color?

Tags: css, material-ui, textfield

I would have black text color, not default gray in the disabled TextField, tried this, based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70943025/239219

```js
<TextField
id="outlined-basic"
value={'https://git.responsive.software/my-app.git'}
fullWidth
size="small"
disabled
variant="filled"
inputProps={{ style: { color: 'black' } }}
/>
```

But this colors text when it is selected. I need black also for unselected text.

[image]

It is also interesting, why my attempt does not work. I guess MUI uses a textfield behind their customized solution. Then why the passed `color` attribute does not change attribute as in a normal css it would change?

Comment: You may find some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669777/material-ui-how-to-change-the-font-colour-of-a-disabled-input-text-field

Answer (score 0):

You could add a style specifically if `disabled=true`. Like this:

```
// STYLES
export const StyledTextField = styled(TextField, {
  shouldForwardProp: (props) => props !== 'disabled', 
})<{ disabled: boolean }>(({ disabled }) => ({
  color: disabled : 'black' ? 'pink',
}));

// IN THE COMPONENT
<StyledTextField
id="outlined-basic"
value={'https://git.responsive.software/my-app.git'}
fullWidth
size="small"
disabled
variant="filled"
inputProps={{ style: { color: 'black' } }}
/>
```

(`shouldForwardProp` makes sure the disabled prop isn't added to the DOM)

Alternatively...

TextField doesn't have a specific disabled class, but if you can change your code to use InputBase instead, you can utilize the disabled class. This CSS is applied when `disabled=true` in your component. https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input-base/#css

```
import { inputBaseClasses } from '@mui/material';

...

[`&.${inputBaseClasses.disabled}`]: {
   color: 'black',
},
```